# Inserting mutable pairs into a mutable list

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

How can I push a mutable pair onto a stack such that i'm only creating one stack. I have some code that works but creates lists within lists within lists.... Here is what I believe should work but throws an error.

```
(define func (arg1 arg2 arg3) // Where arg3 is an empty list
    (mappend (mcons arg1 arg2) arg3))
```

The above code complains and says: "mcar: expects argument of type ; given ...
Can anyone show me how I can get a result that looks like so,: (list (arg1 arg2)
                                                                     (arg# arg#)
                                                                     ...)

Comment: Can you provide some examples of inputs and desired corresponding outputs?

Comment: Certainly, for example: I want to store and append pairs into one list. (mappend (mcons 3 4) (mcons 4 5) empty) should result in (list (list 3 4) (list 4 5)) or that is what I would like.

Comment: Your input/output is not clear. Call your function "f" or whatever and show the call and the desired output for a couple of cases. Edit this into your question above. Like `(f 3 4 '()) ==> ((3 . 4))` for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
(mcons (mcons arg1 arg2) arg3)
```

or (your question is not very clear)

```
(cons (list 'a 'b) '())
```

Also, the syntax in your question doesn't make any sense. It should be something like

```
(define func (lambda (arg1 arg2 arg3)
                ...body...))
```

Comment: I have tried that and it works but the issue is the shape of the result is not what I am looking for. For example with the given code you provided the result could look like this:(mcons
 (mcons 42 147)
 (mcons
  (mcons 48 69). These are lists in lists, where i would like to just append each mcons into a larger (single) mcons.

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you want is:

```
  (define (f a b c)
    (mlist (mlist a b) c))
```

This produces the following result:

```
  > (f 3 4 (mlist 4 5))
  {{3 4} {4 5}}
```